# How to get file directory from webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, video, google-chrome-extension

currently i am creating chrome extension (video donwloader) and I am willing to get the video path 
`http://<IP ADDRESS>/video.mp4` from webpage where video is. and also in some websites they are using iframes to display the video and i also need to get the video from that url of iframe, here is one scenario: website is using another website for the video for example:  `example.com` has a video on link `example.com/video/ID/312351` and video source on `videos.example.com/id/31312/video.mp4` and `secondexample.com` is using `example.com/video/ID/312351` url in iframe to get the video, and when i am on `secondexample.com` i also need to get the video source (`videos.example.com/id/31312/video.mp4`) from `example.com`, Is this possible? and how. Thank You!

Comment: You can declare your [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) with `"all_frames":true` and an instance of it will run in each iframe so you'll be able to see `location.href` to decide what to do, and either use a) the standard DOM communication via [parent.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) or b) background script relay via [extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: can you show me the example?

Comment: I don't have any.  There should be some in the documentation and in other answers.

Comment: thats bad, but thank you